# Как работает геолокация в Uber или Yandex taxi?

Tags: java, android, c#, геолокация

Начал делать приложение и возник вопрос, а как правильно делать геолокацию.
Есть несколько клиентов, каждый клиент должен получать геолокацию остальных клиентов и передавать свою.

Была мысль сделать сервер, на который я буду с клиента передавать геолокацию и сохранять ее в базе данных и после чего передавать этому клиенту геолокацию остальных пользователей списком. Ограничить все это дело 5 секундами (т.е запрос раз в 5-10 секунд). Но тогда получается, что запросы на сервер будут слишком частые, что снизит производительность сервера при большом количестве пользователей.

Так вот вопрос в том, как правильно сделать передачу и получение геолокации.

Comment: Слишком частые, снизит производительность, большое количество пользователей - что это вообще значит? Вы на сервер же будете отсылать координаты только тех, кто в движении. Допустим, у вас 1000 клиентов, все в движении, это 1000 запросов за 10 секунд, то есть 100 в секунду — это ерунда для сервера, особенно если вы в памяти/кеше будете держать положение клиента, отправляя его в бд время от времени - то и 1000 запросов в секунду ерунда, скорее канал забьется чем сервер устанет

Comment: Смысл чем-то напоминает DC++, где за поиск файла (локации) отвечает сервер, но после нахождения все операции происходят между клиентами. Типа запрос nearMe выдаёт клиентские IP/ID, находящиеся поблизости, а далее клиентские приложения "общаются между собой". Для снижения нагрузки нужно использовать timeout. Если клиент передаёт данные чаще чем timeout, то откидывать их. А лучше запрашивать данные раз в timeout. Разрыв соединения равен трём timeout. Конкретное значение timeout выводить эмпирически. По-моему как-то так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Для начала вам нужно определить списки подписок. Т.е. каким клиентам интересно положение конкретно этого клиента. Врядли интерес всех ко всем.
- Далее, с клиента передавать на сервер новое месторасположение только в том случае, если оно изменилось (скажем, на 20 метров). Но не чаще, чем раз в n-секунд
- По приходу на сервер месторасположение клиента рассылается всем, кто в нем заинтересован и, при необходимости, пишется в базу

Answer (score 1):

Мысль правильная, просто передавать нужно по протоколу UDP. Он значительно легче. И передавать можно реже.
А еще можно не передавать с клиента, а запрашивать. Например, запрос на получение текущей геолокации остальных запрашивается только в том случае, если кто-то открыл в приложении карту.